# how can i change a multi picklist value's label?

Tags: multi-select, customlabel

I would like to know how can I change a multi-picklist label? Meaning i have values:

1) Dept.

2) Sch.

But i would like to display 'Department' for Dept. and 'School' for Sch in page layout. Its something like back-end is storing 'Dept.' or 'Sch.' but on screen display 'Department' or 'School'.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not set/change the picklist Values as you want it to be saved in server and use translation workbench to translate the picklist Values to what you want the users to see.

Comment: hi yuval, you're right. I just found out translation did the tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of using Visualforce, there's no way to do so. The label and value of picklist items are the same. You can provide "translations" for values in a picklist, but this won't have the effect you want without significant effort.

Comment: actually it's already in place in our environment but that was implemented by our previous developer who have already left. i don't see any custom VF page for this. it seems like there are some other mapping else where to change the value label. why i say so is is because if i add a new value 'Shc.' into the multi-picklist then it display 'Shc.' on screen but if i add a new value 'Sch.' into the multi-picklist then it display 'School' on screen. anywhere can do such mapping for multi-picklist's values and the label to display on screnn?